# I can't run my accuracy test for a model, is something wrong with my code?

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colaboratory, logistic-regression

Everything runs right until I get to the final lines of code that simply don't run. No error or anything, it just doesn't execute and I don't know why.
I want to test the accuracy of a model to predict the rating a person gave to a hotel based on a review, so it includes integers and strings, but to what I know, all my data is set as a str

**Code:**

(I have some variables with data text, but are too long so I will just skip that)

```
train_reviews = [r1, r2]
train_reviews_label = [rating1, rating2]
test_reviews = [r3]
test_reviews_label = [rating3]



    vectorizer = CountVectorizer() # Countvectorizer
    train_vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_reviews) # fit_transform fits the train tweets and returns the sparse matrix of the tweets
    model = LogisticRegression() # create a LogisticRegression Model
    model.fit(train_vect, train_reviews_label) # Fit the data values to the model


I even made a prediction test and it ran just fine:

    #Prediction test
    test_vect = vectorizer.transform(reviews)
    result = model.predict(test_vect)
    print('Actual Category: {}\nPredicted Category: {}'.format(rating3, result[0]))


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(tokens, reviews, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

def train_model(reviews_to_train,train_labels):
  """
  param: reviews_to_train - list of tweets to train on
  return: the vectorizer, the logistic regression model, the train_vector
  """
  
  train_reviews = [" ".join(t) for t in reviews_to_train]
  train_reviews_label = [l for l in train_labels]
  
  
  
  # vectorizer = Initialize CountVectorizer
  # fit the train_tweets in the CountVectorizer using the vectorizer's fit method
  # train_vect = get the sparse matrix of the train_tweets from the vectorizer using the transform function
  
  # model = initialize a Logistic Regression model
  # fit train_vect and train_tweets_label using the fit function of LogisticRegression

  vectorizer = CountVectorizer() # Countvectorizer
  train_vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_reviews) # fit_transform fits the train tweets and returns the sparse matrix of the tweets
  model = LogisticRegression() # create a LogisticRegression Model
  model.fit(train_vect, train_reviews_label) # Fit the data values to the model
  
  
  return model,vectorizer


def predict(reviews_to_test, vectorizer, model):
  """
  param: reviews_to_test - list of tweets to test the model on
  param: vectorizer - the CountVectorizer
  param: model - the LogisticRegression model
  return result (the prediction), the test_vect
  """
  
  test_reviews = [" ".join(t) for t in  reviews_to_test]
  
  print (test_reviews)
  ### Your code starts here ###
  
  # test_vect = transform the test_tweets to sparce matrix using the vectorizer's transform function
  test_vect = vectorizer.transform(test_reviews)
  # result = predict the result using the model's predict function on test_vect
  result = model.predict(test_vect)
  
  return result
```

**And this are the lines that don't run for apparently reason:**

```
model,train_countvect = train_model(X_train,y_train)
#Predict labels for test set
y_pred = predict(X_test,train_countvect,model)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: The indentation here is incorrect. Please provide a [mre] and do not separate the part that does not work from the part which does. The problem is likely an indentation error or something similar, which requires that we see the complete code which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

The prediction should be

```
#Predict labels for test set
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

After that this is correct: compare `y_pred` with `y_test` using `metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)`